# Javascript, CSS: displaying a hidden div not working?

Tags: javascript, css

I know this is a question that's been asked a hundred times but I can't figure out why it's not working on me site.

Javascript:

```
<script>
  function show(boxid){
    document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="visible";
  }

  function hide(boxid){
    document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="hidden";
  }
</script>
```

HTML (PHP generated):

```
echo '<div id="selectedBookingActionLink">';
  echo '<a href="#" onClick="show(cancelPopUp)">Cancel</a>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="cancelPopUp">';
  echo '<div class="question">Cancel?</div>';
  echo '<div class="answer">Yes</div>';
  echo '<div class="answer">No</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

CSS:

```
#cancelPopUp
{
  width: 260px;
  height: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to change the visibility property of the cancelPopUp div when the user clicks the "Cancel" link. I've done some research and found that why I'm doing should work. Yet the pop up box does not appear.

Comment: Not related to this issue, but I think it is better to use `display: none` for hiding a div than using `visibility: hidden` because the latter only makes it invisible but the height will be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use quotes when passing the ID of the div to the `show` function:

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="show(\'cancelPopUp\')">Cancel</a>';
```

Comment: +1 I initially didn't notice that `boxid` was a parameter to the function :)

Answer (score 0):

**I've posted a working version of your code here → http://jsfiddle.net/matbloom/uHQsd/**

1. First, make sure you have positioned your JS in the head of your document, above the body.
2. Second, don't forget to add single quotes inside the onClick.

   ```
   <a href="#" onClick="show('cancelPopUp')">Cancel</a>
   ```
3. Third, I would suggest using the 'display' property vs 'visibility'.

Also, I've provided a simple toggle function which may work better for your application.

Hope this helps!

HTML:

```
<div id="selectedBookingActionLink"> 
    <a href="#" onClick="show('cancelPopUp')">Cancel</a>
</div>

<div id="cancelPopUp" style="display:none;">
    <div class="question">Cancel?</div>
    <div class="answer">Yes</div>
    <div class="answer">No</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cancelPopUp {
    width: 260px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

JS:

```
function show(boxid) {
    document.getElementById(boxid).style.display = "block";
}

function hide(boxid) {
    document.getElementById(boxid).style.display = "none";
}

/* Optional toggle function */
function toggle(boxid) {
    var e = document.getElementById(boxid);
    if (e.style.display == "block") {
        e.style.display = "none";
    } else { 
        e.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```